# How to delete the shortest word from the linked list without array? C/C++

Tags: c++, string, list, pointers

How can I delete the shortest word from a linked list without array? I am a first course student and learning pointers with linked list etc.
This is my last task to do and I'm stuck.

This code finds the shortest word of the list and I need to delete that word. I don't know how to delete that specific word.

My problem is that the `del` function deletes wrong word:

```
void del (Node *shorter)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = shorter->next;
    shorter->next = temp->next;
    cout<<"Deleted: "<<temp->data<<endl;
    delete temp;
}
```

This is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& source, const std::string& delimiters = " ") {
    std::size_t prev = 0;
    std::size_t currentPos = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> results;

    while ((currentPos = source.find_first_of(delimiters, prev)) != std::string::npos) {
        if (currentPos > prev) {
            results.push_back(source.substr(prev, currentPos - prev));
        }
        prev = currentPos + 1;
    }
    if (prev < source.length()) {
        results.push_back(source.substr(prev));
    }
    return results;
}

struct Node {
    std::string data;
    Node* next;
};
struct Node* head = NULL;

Node* createList() {
    string text;
    cout << "Write text: ";
    getline(cin, text);

    Node *head = new Node();
    head->next = NULL;
    Node *current = head;

    string delimiters = " ,.-':;?()+*/%$#!\"@^&";
    auto results = split(text, delimiters);

    bool isFirst = true;
    for (const auto& word : results) {
        if (isFirst) {
            current->data = word;
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
            Node *newNode = new Node();
            newNode->data = word;
            current->next = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void del (Node *shorter)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = shorter->next;
    shorter->next = temp->next;
    cout<<"Deleted: "<<temp->data<<endl;
    delete temp;
}


void findShortestWord(Node* head) {
    Node *current = head;
    Node *shorter = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->data.size() < shorter->data.size()) {
            shorter->data = current->data;
        } else if (current->data.size() > shorter->data.size()) {
            current = current->next;
        } else if (current->data.size() == shorter->data.size()) {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    cout << "_____________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "Shortest word: " << shorter->data << "                                |" <<endl;
    cout << "_____________________________________________________________|" << endl;
    del(shorter);
}

void print(Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL and cout << endl)
        return;
    cout<<"\nThe word you entered: ";
    cout << head->data << ' ';
    print(head->next);
}

int main() {

     Node *head = createList();
     print(head);
     findShortestWord(head);
     print(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Some questions to ponder: what does `shorter` point to at the end of the loop? Does `del(shorter)` actually delete the node pointed to by `shorter`? What happens if `shorter` was the last node of the list?

Comment: Draw the act of removing a node out on paper. You will see the node previous to the node being deleted is also needed.

Comment: Memory leak: https://godbolt.org/z/11Ezohr9c

Comment: Your `del` is wrong it deletes next item not current one. You need `void del (Node **shorter)` or  `void del (Node *&shorter)`.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks but I tried it and nothing changes.

Comment: Since you have to change more then just declaration of this function. This was just a hint.

Comment: @Quimby No and I don’t really know how to do it

Comment: Learn to use Debugger ASAP. The more skilled developer is then less he needs use the debugger. Newbie should use it constantly. There plenty instruction how to do it and it is easy.

Comment: @MarekR I'm sorry to ask but could you help me to complete the code? Because I’ve been trying to do it for over two days and have to deliver by tomorrow

Comment: Yes I could (I already have something), but you will not learn anything with this approach.

Comment: @Gronila Then I suggest to learn, it's very useful skill.

Comment: @MarekR Yes I understand that and I don't know what to do, because I need to write another code and do another university tasks because it is the end of the semester.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice? [How to delete the shortest word from the list using C++? Without an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437697/how-to-delete-the-shortest-word-from-the-list-using-c-without-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I won't give a complete answer, but
here's an example linked list. "it" is the shortest word. If we draw removing that node, it looks like this:

```
(head)           (shorter prev)   (shorter)        (shorter next)
┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐
│  hello   │────>│  world   │────>│    it    │────>│  other   │
└──────────┘     └──────────┘     └──────────┘     └──────────┘

Unlink "it"
┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐
│  hello   │────>│  world   │───┐ │    it    │ ┌──>│  other   │
└──────────┘     └──────────┘   ↓ └──────────┘ ↑   └──────────┘
                                └──────────────┘
                                
New list
┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐     ┌──────────┐
│  hello   │────>│  world   │────>│  other   │
└──────────┘     └──────────┘     └──────────┘
```

Now you can `delete` shorter.

We can't unlink a node without knowing the address of the previous node. (If the previous node is `nullptr` we are deleting the `head`.) So, in `findShortestWord()`, while walking the list to find the shortest word, keep track of the previous node and use that in `del()`.

Another option is to change the struct to include the a `prev` member (doubly linked list).

```
struct Node {
    std::string data;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};
```

Note: You can unlink a node without any `temp` variables.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try first option because I have to do only in single linked list.

Answer (score 0):

There are some edge cases you miss here. what if the word you delete is the last word in your list? In that case your code will not work properly beacause notice that:  ***temp=shortest->next*** but ***shortest->next=NULL*** and therefore when you will execute the code line ***shortest->next=temp->next*** the compiler throw to you ***exception*** that temp was ***nullptr***.

Comment: Could you help complete the code? Because I’ve been trying to do it for over two days and have to deliver by tomorrow